# How save multiselect values to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I add values to string field in database from multiple select.

I have field in database:

```
t.string   "types"
```

and view:

```
<%= f.select :order, [["One", 1], ["Two", 2], ["Three", 3]], {}, { :class => 'form-control', :multiple => true } %>
```

Maybe serialize or json is goot idea? Is it possible save and simple way read this?

Comment: what are you going to do with the values after you save them? Does your DB have options for an array type (such as postgresql?).

Answer (score 1):

You can use rails serialize on the column:

```
serialize :order, Hash
```

Or for JSON (depending what you want to do with it):

```
serialize :order, JSON
```

However, the columns needs to be of type 'text' not 'string' for serialize to work, so be sure to create a migration to change the column type.

```
rails g migration change_order_type_in_table_name

class ChangeOrderTypeInTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :my_table, :order, :text
  end

  def down
    change_column :my_table, :order, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a class to [serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class):

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      serialize :order, Array
    end
    The above ensures that order as an Array:

    User.new
    #=> #<User id: nil, order: [], created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
    Note that you might have to convert existing fields if the types don't match.
```